# what is session_register alternative

Tags: php, session

I'm using old php script that depends on session_register to gives warning messages but later after my hosting update PHP version to `[PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14]`

check.php

```
<?PHP
$msg= "Wrong Login";
session_register('msg');
header("Location: login.php ");
?>
```

login.php

```
<?PHP 
echo $msg; 
session_unregister('msg')
?>
```

it should gives Wrong Login but it gives nothing.
so any help please why `session_register` and is there any way else can do me the same
~ Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should directly access the $_SESSION[] array to alter session variables.

Also you should make sure you have called session_start(); before doing anything related with sessions.